# WPF D3DImage and SharpDX

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, d3dimage

I have written a SharpDX Rendering Software and need to render on a D3DImage Surface.
I have followed this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28526/Introduction-to-D3DImage but have not idea how to implement the SharpDX part.

How do I implement the functions:

IntPtr InitializeScene(),
void RenderScene(...),
void ReleaseScene()

How to Create the Swapchain and how do I get the pointer to it for the WPF part ?
Does SharpDX need some kind of Window Handle of the WPF Window ?

Comment: That article is from **2008**, and only seem to cover the D3D-WPF interop, you will need other documentation for setting up the rendering pipeline. However, SlimDX is no longer maintained, so it seem unwise to use it for a new project. If you just want some fairly simple 3D graphics you can just use WPF 3D directly. If you want a high performance rendering engine you are probably better of using native code.

Comment: WPF is based on DirectX9 and will never evolve. D3DImage has lots of performance and airspace issues (https://dwayneneed.github.io/wpf/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications.html). SharpDX is not longer maintained. So you're sailing towards big legacy problems. For a modern setup you should use WinUI3 (even if it has some issue, it's the future). That being said, if you want to keep with what you have, you "just" have to convert C++ code in the article to SharpDX code. IMHO, SharpDX is a problem if you don't know it because it doesn't look like the C/C++ equivalent.